# css - three columns, same size on bigger devices, center element to get to top and two others below that on smaller devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

There are three columns:

```
b  a  c
|  |  |
```

in large devices.

I want to show them like:

```
  a
  |
b   c
|   |
```

on small devices.

My code is:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    b
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    a
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    c
</div>
```

and my attempt was to change the position of second div that is a and first div with jquery and then leave `a` unchanged and `b` to have `col-xs-8 col-sm-4` and for `c` to have `col-xs-4 col-sm-4`.

Is it an standard way to do this?!

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself:

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-12">
a //so it shows only on small devices
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4">
b
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4">
a //so it shows only on large devices
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
c
</div>
```

Thanks all even those downvoted :)

Answer (score -2):

Something like this. Please check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ it's a really nice documentation.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
</div>
```